# Custom GroupBy Functions for JuliaDB

Tags: julia

I'm reading in some stock trade data using the JuliaDB `loadtable` function and I want to group all dates that are the same and apply a custom function.

The custom function is meant to take the group of trades of the same date and return a single trade with volume being the sum and trade price being the volume weighted average. I can get the sum of the volume but I am struggling to get the volume weighted average.

```
function vol_weighted_avg(x)
return (x.price .* x.volume) / sum(x.volume)
end
```

This is the function but it doesn't work with 
`groupby(vol_weighted_avg, trades, :date)`

I've spent a long time playing with the groupby and I haven't been able to figure it out nor have I come across documentation that shows how to do something like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. My answer is for Julia 0.6 and JuliaDB 0.8.4.
What you have to understand is that `groupby` returns a vector of `NamedTuple`s. Therefore the simplest approach to the implementation of your function would be:

```
vol_weighted_avg(x) =
    sum(getindex.(x, :price) .* getindex.(x,:volume)) / sum(getindex.(x,:volume))
```

you can use `mean` from `StatsBase` to achieve the same:

```
using StatsBase
vol_weighted_avg2(x) = mean(getindex.(x, :price), Weights(getindex.(x,:volume)))
```

Unfortunately both versions will not scale well if your data is very large. You could write a custom weighted mean calculation for `OnlineStats` but in this case I did find it a bit cumbersome. However, in this case it is simple enough to write a function that can be passed to `groupreduce` like this:

```
function vol_weighted_avg3(a,b)
    ap, av, bp, bv = a.price, a.volume, b.price, b.volume
    @NT(price=(ap*av + bp*bv)/(av+bv), volume=av+bv)
end
```

(the only drawback is that you will get a column with totals of volumes traded).

Now let us see the three functions in action:

```
julia> srand(1);

julia> trades = table(rand(10^7), rand(10^7), rand(1:4, 10^7),
                      names=[:price,:volume,:date], pkey=:date);

julia> groupby(vol_weighted_avg, trades, :date)
Table with 4 rows, 2 columns:
date  vol_weighted_avg
──────────────────────
1     0.500097
2     0.499923
3     0.50013
4     0.499711

julia> groupby(vol_weighted_avg2, trades, :date)
Table with 4 rows, 2 columns:
date  vol_weighted_avg2
───────────────────────
1     0.500097
2     0.499923
3     0.50013
4     0.499711

julia> groupreduce(vol_weighted_avg3, trades, :date)
Table with 4 rows, 3 columns:
date  price     volume
─────────────────────────
1     0.500097  1.2482e6
2     0.499923  1.25025e6
3     0.50013   1.25168e6
4     0.499711  1.249e6
```

You can check their relative performance to find out that the last option (with `groupreduce`) is much faster and memory-efficient even for in-memory data:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark groupby($vol_weighted_avg, $trades, :date)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  2.16 GiB
  allocs estimate:  105003042
  --------------
  minimum time:     3.301 s (15.41% GC)
  median time:      3.321 s (16.95% GC)
  mean time:        3.321 s (16.95% GC)
  maximum time:     3.341 s (18.47% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          2
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark groupby($vol_weighted_avg2, $trades, :date)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  1.71 GiB
  allocs estimate:  85003045
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.689 s (15.23% GC)
  median time:      2.748 s (17.09% GC)
  mean time:        2.748 s (17.09% GC)
  maximum time:     2.807 s (18.88% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          2
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark groupreduce($vol_weighted_avg3, $trades, :date)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  11.50 KiB
  allocs estimate:  254
  --------------
  minimum time:     103.955 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      106.777 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        108.810 ms (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     148.807 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          47
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Most of my trouble came from not understanding what the groupby function was returning and then not knowing how to average over a NamedTuple. I was able to get a different workaround that returned the desired results but I will try your method and report back on the perfromance